# Spring Boot jar executable - How to generate files to different directory similar as maven-dependency-plugin does

Tags: maven, spring-boot, maven-assembly-plugin

As straich question, why spring-boot-maven-plugin works but maven-assembly-plugin not in the pom below?

I have googled few hours and I red somewhere that we don't need maven-assembly-plugin  if we use spring-boot-maven-plugin. It doesn't answer my question since I want to have more control in which folder my files are genereated. Along that, if I "mvn clean compile package assembly:single" I get two executable jars, one outcome of spring-boot-maven-plugin and another outcome of maven-assembly-plugin in my project target folder. The one generated by spring-boot-maven-plugin runs as expected when I start via command line (java -jar aws.scheduller-1.jar. On the opposite, if I try java -jar aws.scheduller-1-jar-with-dependencies.jar I get a message complaining that it wasn't possible to load ...config.BootApp (I googled a bit and I guess it is something related to certain default profile in Spring Boot).

That said, how can I use maven to package Spring-boot dependency in different folder than default target directory?

Main Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan({ "br.com.mycompany.tasks","br.com.mycompany.utils" })
@PropertySource("file:C:/temp/application.properties")
//@PropertySource("file:/home/ec2-user/JOBs/application.properties")
public class BootApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(new Object[] { BootApp.class }, args);

    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>grpAwsScheduller</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws.scheduller</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceencoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceencoding>
        <logback.version>1.1.9</logback.version>
        <logstash-logback-encode.version>4.8</logstash-logback-encode.version>
        <spring-boot-starter.version>1.4.3.RELEASE</spring-boot-starter.version>
        <aws-java-sdk.version>1.11.73</aws-java-sdk.version>
        <jdk.version.version>1.7</jdk.version.version>
        <project.build.directory>C:/temp</project.build.directory>
        <!-- Maven versions -->
        <!-- https://maven.apache.org/plugins/ -->
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.6.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-dependency-plugin.version>3.0.0</maven-dependency-plugin.version>
    </properties>



    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>${aws-java-sdk.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.73</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId> <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sqs</artifactId> 
            <version>${aws-java-sdk.version}</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId> 
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sns</artifactId> <version>${aws-java-sdk.version}</version> 
            </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-starter.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>${logstash-logback-encode.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <mainClass>br.com.MyCompany.config.BootApp</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>br.com.MyCompany.config.BootApp</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assemble-all</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- <excludes> <exclude>**/log4j.properties</exclude> </excludes> -->
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>br.com.MyCompany.config.BootApp</mainClass>
                            <classpathPrefix>dependency-jars/</classpathPrefix>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-dependency-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: are you trying to package a jar similar to spring boot but using maven-assembly ? It's gona be hard though.. If you open SpringBoot generated jar, you'll see many things were moved around (your classes are in BOOT-INF folder, SpringBoot is specified in the Manifest.mf....

Comment: Maven assembly plugin with descriptor jar-with-dependencies actually includes the dependencies in "unpacked" form i.e classes. While unpacking it overwrites the files inside META-INF. You can see the contents of your jar "aws.scheduller-1-jar-with-dependencies.jar" and inside META-INF check the manifest file. Does it have an entry as: Start-Class: YOUR-MAIN-CLASS-SHOULD-BE-HERE